# Copy paste entire worksheet with InputBox

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code and I am trying to do a simple task, which apparently it is not so simple to me. I want to say to vba which sheet to copy (here the functionality of the InputBox, where I insert the sheet name) and then, if exists (i.e. if the name is correct) perform the copy paste in the sheet20, if it does not exist, go to exitmysub.

Now, I have two problems:

1) It does not copy paste. Or at least, not always. Sometimes yes, sometimes not. And I really dont understand why (I always put the correct sheet names)

2) Even if the name is correct, the code runs the msgbox ("Invalid Sheet Name"). While I wantthat it triggers only if the sheet name I put does not exist.

Thank you for you help!

```
Option Explicit

Dim text As String, ws As Worksheet


Sub copyentiresheet()

text = InputBox("Write here the Local Deposit Sheet you want to update", "Update Local Deposit Monitoring")

On Error GoTo exitmysub
Sheet20.Cells.Clear
Set ws = Sheets(text)
    ws.Cells.Copy

Sheets20.Paste


exitmysub:
MsgBox ("Invalid Sheet Name")

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you need to specify a range, so try using `ws.cells.copy Sheet20.range("A1")`. Also it's worth noting that in one place you use  `Sheet20`and the other you use `Sheets20`

Comment: @Brotato sheets is a typo. And you are right about the reference...

Comment: I'd look at putting together a userform that has combobox with a list of the sheets in your workbook to select from.  This way, you're not dependent on the user's typing skills.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414880/create-drop-down-list-in-input-box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Copy Entire Sheet

### Highlights

> - **InputBox** VBA Help: If the user clicks Cancel, the function returns a    zero-length string (`""`).
> - If the sheet's **CodeName** is wrong, the code won't compile. No error handling    necessary.
> - Use the **`With`** Statement to avoid declaring unnecessary object references.
> - Refer to a workbook using **`CodeName.Parent`** to avoid wrecking yourself about choosing between **`ActiveWorkbook`**, **`ThisWorkbook`** or workbook by name.
> - **`Exit Sub`** before (in between) error handlers.

### The Code

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyEntireSheet()

  Dim text As String

  text = InputBox("Write here the Local Deposit Sheet you want to update", _
      "Update Local Deposit Monitoring")

  If text = "" Then Exit Sub ' If the user clicks Cancel.

  Sheet20.Cells.Clear ' If sheet's code name is wrong, code won't compile.

  On Error GoTo SourceSheetErr

  With Sheet20.Parent.Worksheets(text)

    On Error GoTo RangeErr
    .Cells.Copy Sheet20.Cells

  End With

Exit Sub

SourceSheetErr:
  MsgBox "Invalid Source Sheet Name."
Exit Sub

RangeErr:
  MsgBox "(Copy) Range Error."

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
Option Explicit

Dim text As String, ws As Worksheet

Sub copyentiresheet()

text = InputBox("Write here the Local Deposit Sheet you want to update", "Update Local Deposit Monitoring")

On Error GoTo ErrorMySub
Sheet20.Cells.Clear
Set ws = Sheets(text)
ws.Cells.Copy Sheet20.Range("A1")

ExitMySub:
Exit Sub

ErrorMySub:
MsgBox ("Invalid Sheet Name")

End Sub
```